# XML Parsing Error: not well-formed in FireFox but good in Chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox

I using jQuery Ajax like below:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'servlet/*****Servlet',
      dataType: "text",
      success: function(data) {
        var subareaCoordsPGs = preprocessCoords(data);
      }
    });
```

it works good even i did not set the dataType in Chrome, however, it failed in FF with XML parsing error.

> Response Headersview source 
>  Server   Apache-Coyote/1.1
>   Transfer-Encoding chunked
>  Date    Tue, 04 Oct 2011 00:08:08 GMT
>   Request Headersview source
>  Host   localhost:8080
>   User-Agent    Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.2; WOW64; rv:7.0.1)
>   Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1
>  Accept   text/plain, */*; q=0.01
>   Accept-Language   en-us,en;q=0.5
>  Accept-Encoding  gzip, deflate
>   Accept-Charset    ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
>
>   Connection    keep-alive
>  X-Requested-With XMLHttpRequest
>
>   Referer   http://localhost:8080/**/
>  Cache-Control max-age=0
>
> XML Parsing Error: not well-formed Location:
>   moz-nullprincipal:{2f6a8381-b987-448b-88c2-e89c4e13440b} Line Number
>   1, Column 4:
>
> 534@151.248078368847 -33.9353900931769,151.247877472978
>   -33.9360784582012,151.24...
>   ------^

after searched, i know it is good to set the proper data type, i want it to be parsed just as normal text, but why **Intelligent Guess** not works in FF, even i set it's type is **"text"** explicitly?

Comment: Note that even if you receive this message, your success call might be triggered with the data.  The latest version of firefox may complain but then still continue, or at least in my case Firefox 55 did.  This error message acted as a red herring for a while for me as I assumed it was fatal.

Comment: @J.Allen: I am facing the same issue. I am seeing this issue in the latest version of firefox. Any ideas to resolve it?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Your server is not returning a content-type, so Firefox assumes that since this is _XML_HttpRequest your response might be XML and tries to parse it.  When that fails, it stops trying and reports that this wasn't XML after all.

Chrome likely does the same but doesn't report anything.

I suggest actually sending a Content-Type header indicating what your data is.

Comment: thanks for you hints. i had set the Content-Type text/plain;charset=UTF-8 using jQuery Ajax like set the parameter contentType: "text/plain; charset=UTF-8",and it still works for Chrome but not for FireFox

Comment: @qc999 I have no idea what the jQuery thing does.  Does it call overrideMimeType on the XHR object?

Comment: @ Boris Zbarsky i had checked the request header from the FireBug, it is looks like this:Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.2; WOW64; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1
Accept: text/plain, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest  so i assume it had override content type.but still have the same XML parse issue.

Comment: @qc999 the request header is not the question.  The question is what the _response_ header for Content-Type is.  And your server is not sending one.  So XHR falls back to assuming it's XML unless told otherwise via `overrideMimeType`.

Comment: @ Boris Zbarsky thanks for you help, i found the errors are still there. but if i set the dataType is "text", the FireFox can parse it. Even some Gson still need be parsed as plain text.

Comment: In order to set the correct content type, I have set config in the Appache or in the .htaccess:
AddType text / plain .hbs (All * .hbs should ship with content-type text.) Firefox was happy.

Comment: Hi Boris, I'm also getting the exact error. I have a Python server, angular-js script on front-end. I'm making ajax calls to my server and as you've pointed out to set 'content-type', I've tried that, but the error still persists!

Comment: @rv7 Hard to say more without details.  Do you have a link?

Comment: Thank you Boris for replying. Well, it's strange that the error disappeared about half an hour after I commented. So, cheers!

Comment: Its still happening for me with Blazor.. I viewed the request and it does contain "text/html" content-type.. If I change it to text/plain, the HTML renders in the browser (instead of the markup)..

Comment: Tim, it's hard to say what your situation is... Since you talk about rendering, it doesn't sound like you're in the XMLHttpRequest setup that the original question was about?

Comment: Thanks, my header had `text` but it should've been `text/event-stream`, that cleared the error.

Answer (score 4):

Just Add this code. The problem is the server did not specify the mime type and firefox takes it to be xml. This code will specify what Mime type the xhr response is going to be.

```
beforeSend: function(xhr){  xhr.overrideMimeType( "text/plain; charset=x-user-defined" );},
```

Comment: Or a bit shorter:
`:beforeSend: function(xhr){ xhr.overrideMimeType( "text/plain; charset=utf-8" );},`