# XML Parsing Error: not well-formed Location: only in firefox,

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, firefox, iframe

i am using Jquery to find an element in a XML. but in firefox i am receiving an error. here is an simple example. and this code should be run in a iframe. some times its work without error in normally. but with iframe, definitely error will occur. and i am using this code in a iframe in my project.

error

```
XML Parsing Error: not well-formedLocation:Line Number 1, Column 189:
```

example :

```js
var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><assessmentItem xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsqti_v2p1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsqti_v2p1 http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/qti/qtiv2p1/imsqti_v2p1.xsd" identifier="AM-5283-01" title="AM-5283-01" adaptive="false" timeDependent="false"><itemBody></itemBody></assessmentItem>';
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);
var $xml = $(xmlDoc);
var ai = $xml.find('assessmentItem'); //this line will make error
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: nope - only error, in **every browser** is ... `xml1` is not defined, fix that glaring typo, and then you get ... `xmlDoc1` is not defined, in **every browser** ... but once you fix that second glaring typo, there is no error in **every browser**

Comment: ahhh.. sorry, its typing mistake

Comment: Yes. But even fixing those the code works fine on every browser

Comment: Is the xml hard coded? If not, console log it before parsing. Does it look right on the console

Comment: did you triy with iframes?

Comment: Let's say i did.

Comment: I mean, if you make your code a executable snippet, guess what, it runs in an iframe - I've turned your code into a snippet, and there's no error - so, your issue is *not* with the code you posted

Comment: so how could this error happend? i am using jQuery 2.1.3 and latest version of firefox.

Comment: did you try adding `console.log(xml)` before `var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);` to check it is right? is the XML hardcoded like in your question? is the iframe dynamically generated or just another page? plenty of unknowns, but the code you put in the question has absolutely no problem

Comment: i debugged all lines. but every thing woks fine. even var ai also creating correctly. but only problem is creating this error. xml is coming from database. some times its also generated. but i tried this code in place where in real place of the project. there is no difference xml from db or from string

Comment: if `ai` is correctly created, then the error is NOT in the code you've shown, clearly the error is in code that runs after

Comment: yes. it may be. but if i remove last line there is no error.

Comment: yes, ai is "correct"

Comment: maybe this has something to do with it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642202/xml-parsing-error-not-well-formed-in-firefox-but-good-in-chrome